# Replacing Regex Match with Blank space

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

This should be a simple question, but I cannot find the answer. I need is to replace my Regex Match with blank space. What is the Syntax for this? Here is my Expression:

```
Matcher alphaSourceMatch = Pattern.compile('(?mi)<\\/?\\w*\\b[^>]*>').matcher(alphaSource);
```

I would simply like to replace the pattern with ' '.

Comment: Do you have an example of the text that this pattern is used against? Maybe a before & after (as you would expect it)...

Comment: Its extremely long and cryptic. It is an HTML email. I know that this matcher works, it's just a matter now of replacing the matches with blank space...how is that written? @MarkPond

Comment: @MarkPond Essentially it just removes the content of all tags in an HTML email...leaving me with the plain text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to append the `.replaceAll(' ')` method to your Matcher instance to replace every match with a space.

```
Matcher alphaSourceMatch = Pattern.compile('(?mi)<\\/?\\w*\\b[^>]*>').matcher(alphaSource);
String replacedText = alphaSourceMatch.replaceAll(' ');
```

Docs: [Matcher.replaceAll(string)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_matcher_methods.htm#apex_System_Matcher_replaceAll)

Comment: Thank you! Straightforward enough. I will give it a try.

Comment: Updated my example, since `replaceAll` returns a string.

Comment: Wow you're on it. I was about to ask!